# How to select a time between two intervals from different dataframe, perform functions and remerge to original dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series, subset

This seems like an easy solution, but after trying several things and countless searches over the past few hours I can't seem to get it, hopefully someone here can help. I am trying to subset the rows of one dataframe (`dfdive`) based on a time interval from another summary dataframe (`dfsum`)

My two dataframes:

1. Summary dive data (`dfsum`)

[image: Dive Summary]

2. Dive Data (`dfdive`)

[image: Dive Data]

What I need to do is select only the rows from the second dataframe (`dfdive`) that are between:

1. `dfsum$hour_before` and `dfsum$start`
2. `dfsum$dive_end` and `dfsum$hour_after`

And then perform a series of functions (`sd,mean,median,min,max`) on the selected rows (indicating an hour before the dive and an hour after the dive) for depth and temperature from `dfdive` and merge it as a summary line back to the `divesum` dataframe according to its dive number.

i.e.
[image: desired output]
[image: Desired output]

I have tried several iterations to extract the times using `dplyr` as I am most familiar with it:

```
library(dplyr)
dfdive %>%
  group_by(Ptt) %>% 
  filter(Date >= as_datetime(dfsum$hour_before) & Date <= as_datetime(dfsum$start))
```

but this does not work and neither do any of my other attempts.

Here is the dput of both dataframes.

**dfsum:**

```
structure(list(start = structure(c(1436090880, 1436093580, 1436097300
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), ptt = c("144883", 
"144883", "144883"), dive = 13:15, hour_before = structure(c(1436087280, 
1436089980, 1436093700), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    dive_end = structure(c(1436092320, 1436095680, 1436098610
    ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), hour_after = structure(c(1436095920, 
    1436099280, 1436102210), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame")
```

**dfdive:**

```
 structure(list(Date = structure(c(1436090220, 1436090820, 1436091420, 
    1436092020, 1436092620, 1436093220, 1436093820, 1436094420, 1436095020, 
    1436095620, 1436096220, 1436096820, 1436097420, 1436098020, 1436098620, 
    1436099220, 1436099820, 1436100420, 1436101020, 1436101620, 1436102220, 
    1436102820, 1436103420), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), Depth = c(76.5, 3, 100, 57.5, 4, 3.5, 39, 74.5, 96.5, 
    21.5, 3.5, 4, 15, 121, 13.5, 4, 3, 7, 7, 5, 5, 4.5, 8.5), Temp = c(26.45, 
    29.35, 25.15, 27.8, 29.5, 29.45, 28.7, 26.95, 25.65, 29.1, 29.6, 
    29.65, 29.35, 23.2, 29.2, 29.8, 29.8, 29.35, 29.35, 29.5, 29.45, 
    29.95, 29.45), `Light Level` = c(147.75, 201.5, 129.25, 161.5, 
    200.75, 184.25, 164.5, 142.5, 133.75, 175.75, 186.5, 195, 175.75, 
    119.25, 179.25, 189.75, 181.5, 182, 180.5, 186.25, 180.75, 181, 
    179), Ptt = c(144883, 144883, 144883, 144883, 144883, 144883, 
    144883, 144883, 144883, 144883, 144883, 144883, 144883, 144883, 
    144883, 144883, 144883, 144883, 144883, 144883, 144883, 144883, 
    144883)), row.names = c(NA, -23L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
    )
```

**Note:**

1. I have decreased the resolution of `dfdive` from 10 second intervals to 10 minute intervals for ease of posting here.
2. I have also selected the shortest consecutive dives from my dataframe (dives 13:15)
3. Ptt is the ID number for the animal- I need to group it by Ptt as I have 22 animals

Comment: The `dfsum` data has some missing/extra parentheses

Comment: Should the date be between both criteria or only one per row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The newest development version of `dplyr` has huge improvements on joins.  You can install is using:

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("tidyverse/dplyr")
```

First you need to convert both `ptt/Ptt` columns to the same format.  In your example, one is character and one is numeric.

```
dfsum2 <- dfsum %>% 
    mutate(ptt = as.numeric(ptt))
```

Now you can use the new overlap join.  We compute twice because you have two intervals.  I imagine you want to combine these two together.

```
before <- dfdive %>% 
    right_join(dfsum2, by = join_by("Ptt" == "ptt", between(Date, hour_before, start)))
after <- dfdive %>% 
    right_join(dfsum2, by = join_by("Ptt" == "ptt", between(Date, dive_end, hour_after)))

bind_rows(before, after) %>% 
    group_by(Ptt, dive) %>% 
    summarize(across(c(start, hour_before, dive_end, hour_after), first),
              across(.cols = c(Depth, Temp,`Light Level`), 
                   .fns = c(sd = sd, mean = mean, median = median, min = min, max = max)),
              .groups = "drop")
```

Finally, you can use `group_by`/`summarize`/`across` to compute the statistics.

Comment: Hi Michael, Thank you for your answer. I am having trouble finding the join_by function in my dplyr package- despite having just reinstalled it. Which version of Rstudio/R are you using? Thanks!

Comment: You have to install the development version from Github using the command in my answer.

Comment: Is this some sort non-equi join that you did with `right_join` ? I didn't find anything about that feature with `right_join`

Comment: The NEWS.md file at the GitHub page describes the new non-equi join.  Or use the built-in help `?right_join` after you install the dev version of `dplyr` from GitHub.

Comment: Apparently, one can remove the quotation mark : `dfdive %>% right_join(dfsum2, by = join_by(Ptt == ptt, between(Date, hour_before, start)))`. Have you tried to run this ?

Comment: Yes.  It runs fine both with and without the quotation marks.

Comment: Hi Michael, I had some major issues downloading the new version of `dplyr`- as of this morning I have sorted it and the code works great! Thanks so much for the help and for the intro to the new `dplyr` version :)

Comment: Hi Meg, I'm happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this will work for one of your Ptt groups. You'll need to double check some of the maths in there, the filtering in here something picks up one row of data, sometimes it's more than one, and I couldnt work out if thats what you needed from the question.

I think the key thing really though for you is setting intervals

```
interval <- start_time %--% end_time
```

and using it for filtering (for examples like this I like to mutate a check column in so I can see what's happening, you could just go straight to a filter)

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(
    interval_check = ifelse(Date %within% interval,"yes","no")
  )
```

The code I used.

The join at the bottom is a bit hacky, apologies for that.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

int_before <- dfsum$hour_before %--% dfsum$start

int_after <- dfsum$dive_end %--% dfsum$hour_after

dfsum_before <- dfdive %>%
  mutate(
    before_check = ifelse(Date %within% int_before,paste0(dfsum$start),0)
  ) %>%
  filter(before_check != 0) %>% 
  group_by(before_check) %>% 
  summarise(
    d_min_before = min(Depth, na.rm = T),
    d_max_before = max(Depth, na.rm = T),
    d_med_before = median(Depth, na.rm = T),
    d_mean_before = mean(Depth, na.rm = T),
    d_sd_before = sd(Depth, na.rm = T),
    t_min_before = min(Temp, na.rm = T),
    t_max_before = max(Temp, na.rm = T),
    t_med_before = median(Temp, na.rm = T),
    t_mean_before = mean(Temp, na.rm = T),
    t_sd_before = sd(Temp, na.rm = T)
  ) %>% 
  rename("start_join" = before_check)

dfsum_after <- dfdive %>%
  mutate(
    after_check = ifelse(Date %within% int_after,paste0(dfsum$start),0)
  ) %>%
  filter(after_check != 0) %>% 
  group_by(after_check) %>% 
  summarise(
    d_min_after = min(Depth, na.rm = T),
    d_max_after = max(Depth, na.rm = T),
    d_med_after = median(Depth, na.rm = T),
    d_mean_after = mean(Depth, na.rm = T),
    d_sd_after = sd(Depth, na.rm = T),
    t_min_after = min(Temp, na.rm = T),
    t_max_after = max(Temp, na.rm = T),
    t_med_after = median(Temp, na.rm = T),
    t_mean_after = mean(Temp, na.rm = T),
    t_sd_after = sd(Temp, na.rm = T)
  ) %>% 
  rename("start_join" = after_check)


dfsum <- dfsum %>% 
  mutate(start_join = paste0(start))


dfsum_final <- left_join(dfsum, dfsum_before, by = "start_join") %>% 
  left_join(., dfsum_after, by = "start_join") %>% 
  select(-start_join)
```

If you wanted to do this for multiple groups, you could turn the above into a function, and iterate over your distinct ptts. Although that was hard to demonstrate with your current example data only having the one group.

Hope at least parts of this are useful.

**EDIT**

I copied the wrong script into SO, updated script will work, Sorry!

In terms of the iteration, you could do something like this

```
ptt_func <- function(ptt_filter){
  
  
  int_before <- dfsum$hour_before %--% dfsum$start
  
  int_after <- dfsum$dive_end %--% dfsum$hour_after
  
  dfsum_before <- dfdive %>%
    filter(Ptt == ptt_filter) %>% 
    mutate(
      before_check = ifelse(Date %within% int_before,paste0(dfsum$start),0)
    ) %>%
    filter(before_check != 0) %>% 
    group_by(before_check) %>% 
    summarise(
      d_min_before = min(Depth, na.rm = T),
      d_max_before = max(Depth, na.rm = T),
      d_med_before = median(Depth, na.rm = T),
      d_mean_before = mean(Depth, na.rm = T),
      d_sd_before = sd(Depth, na.rm = T),
      t_min_before = min(Temp, na.rm = T),
      t_max_before = max(Temp, na.rm = T),
      t_med_before = median(Temp, na.rm = T),
      t_mean_before = mean(Temp, na.rm = T),
      t_sd_before = sd(Temp, na.rm = T)
    ) %>% 
    rename("start_join" = before_check)
  
  dfsum_after <- dfdive %>%
    filter(Ptt == ptt_filter) %>% 
    mutate(
      after_check = ifelse(Date %within% int_after,paste0(dfsum$start),0)
    ) %>%
    filter(after_check != 0) %>% 
    group_by(after_check) %>% 
    summarise(
      d_min_after = min(Depth, na.rm = T),
      d_max_after = max(Depth, na.rm = T),
      d_med_after = median(Depth, na.rm = T),
      d_mean_after = mean(Depth, na.rm = T),
      d_sd_after = sd(Depth, na.rm = T),
      t_min_after = min(Temp, na.rm = T),
      t_max_after = max(Temp, na.rm = T),
      t_med_after = median(Temp, na.rm = T),
      t_mean_after = mean(Temp, na.rm = T),
      t_sd_after = sd(Temp, na.rm = T)
    ) %>% 
    rename("start_join" = after_check)
  
  
  dfsum <- dfsum %>% 
    mutate(start_join = paste0(start))
  
  
  dfsum <<- left_join(dfsum, dfsum_before, by = "start_join") %>% 
    left_join(., dfsum_after, by = "start_join") %>% 
    select(-start_join)
  
}  

ptt_func("144883")

## lapply(ptt_list,ptt_func)
```

for the iteration, set all of your ptts as a list and run the code in front of the ##

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I appreciate the time you took to work on this code. Unfortunately, I am still having issues with it selecting the time from `dfsum` and filtering it through `dfdive`- this seems to be the main hold up. When you ran this, were you able to get the correct subset from `dfdive`?

Comment: So in my example the times are drawn out of dfsum in the int_before and int_after objects, and that worked for what I thought you needed to do? is that right? (another thing - I would swap in the summarise section from the other answer as it is miles nicer than mine!)